# Highcharts: Change needle color of Gauge Chart on Hover

Tags: javascript, highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/2egpa8eb/

```
plotOptions: {
  gauge: {
    allowPointSelect: true,
    states: {
      hover: {
        enabled: true,
        marker: {
          fillColor: "#FF0000",
          lineColor: "#0000FF",
          lineWidth: 5
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

I want to change the color of the "needle" on hover and select (see image below). I have used the above options as per api given in http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.gauge.states but it did not work. Is there any way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean tooltip border or other "pointer" ? Could you elaborate what should happen in more details?

Comment: @SebastianBochan I've added an image for better understanding of the problem

Answer (score 2):

You can style the needle on hover using CSS like this:

```
div.highcharts-container:hover g.highcharts-tracker > * {
  fill :#f00;
}
```

You would need to ensure that `div.highcharts-container` was unique to just the charts you are targeting as this example is pretty generic, say you had multiple charts on the same page or using the same CSS for instance, this CSS would target them all.

I'm not sure what you can "select" on these charts to answer your second question.

http://jsfiddle.net/2egpa8eb/1/

```js
$(function() {

  $('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
      type: 'gauge',
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBackgroundImage: null,
      plotBorderWidth: 0,
      plotShadow: false
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Speedometer'
    },

    plotOptions: {
      gauge: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        states: {
          hover: {
            enabled: true,
            marker: {
              fillColor: "#FF0000",
              lineColor: "#0000FF",
              lineWidth: 5
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },

    pane: {
      startAngle: -150,
      endAngle: 150,
      background: [{
        backgroundColor: {
          linearGradient: {
            x1: 0,
            y1: 0,
            x2: 0,
            y2: 1
          },
          stops: [
            [0, '#FFF'],
            [1, '#333']
          ]
        },
        borderWidth: 0,
        outerRadius: '109%'
      }, {
        backgroundColor: {
          linearGradient: {
            x1: 0,
            y1: 0,
            x2: 0,
            y2: 1
          },
          stops: [
            [0, '#333'],
            [1, '#FFF']
          ]
        },
        borderWidth: 1,
        outerRadius: '107%'
      }, {
        // default background
      }, {
        backgroundColor: '#DDD',
        borderWidth: 0,
        outerRadius: '105%',
        innerRadius: '103%'
      }]
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 200,

      minorTickInterval: 'auto',
      minorTickWidth: 1,
      minorTickLength: 10,
      minorTickPosition: 'inside',
      minorTickColor: '#666',

      tickPixelInterval: 30,
      tickWidth: 2,
      tickPosition: 'inside',
      tickLength: 10,
      tickColor: '#666',
      labels: {
        step: 2,
        rotation: 'auto'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'km/h'
      },
      plotBands: [{
        from: 0,
        to: 120,
        color: '#55BF3B' // green
      }, {
        from: 120,
        to: 160,
        color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
      }, {
        from: 160,
        to: 200,
        color: '#DF5353' // red
      }]
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Speed',
      data: [80],
      tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' km/h'
      }
    }]

  });
});
```

```css
div.highcharts-container:hover g.highcharts-tracker > * {
  fill :#f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Why is states option given in the api? What things can I change/format on "hover" and "select" according to the api?

Comment: You edit the formatting for the needle with "dial" but there is no option to format dial on hover or select : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.gauge.dial

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the load event and then attach the custom events by `on` declaration.

```
chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        events:{
            load:function() {
            var chart = this,
                    graph = chart.series[0].data[0].graphic;

            graph
            .on('mouseover',function(){
                graph.attr({
                fill: 'red'
              });
            })
            .on('mouseout',function(){
                graph.attr({
                fill: 'black'
              });
            })
            .on('click', function() {
                graph.attr({
                fill: 'green'
              });
            });
          }
        }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6dbegyvs/

Comment: Thanks. Then what exactly hover and select states in series options are used for? What can we achieve from using those options as given in the api?

Comment: This is workaround which apply styles defuned in attr() object. So are not extracted from series options.